# Add new lines above each existing line in a file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with below lines

```
This is an PLUTO
This is PINEAPPLE
This is ORANGE
This is RICE
```

How do I make a new line above each lines and insert the last string to the new line output as below:

```
PLUTO:
This is an PLUTO
PINEAPPLE:
This is an PINEAPPLE
ORANGE:
This is an ORANGE
RICE:
This is an RICE
```

Thanks

Comment: Just for consistency's sake, where did the "an" come from (or disappear from) on the last 3 lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `awk` to print the last field of each line followed by a colon before printing the line itself:

```
$ awk '{ print $NF ":"; print }' file
PLUTO:
This is an PLUTO
PINEAPPLE:
This is PINEAPPLE
ORANGE:
This is ORANGE
RICE:
This is RICE
```

Variation that uses a single `print` statement but that explicitly prints the output record separator (a newline) and `$0` (the line):

```
awk '{ print $NF ":" ORS $0 }' file
```

Variation using `printf` instead:

```
awk '{ printf("%s:\n%s\n", $NF, $0) }' file
```

---

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed 'h; s/.* //; s/$/:/; G' file
PLUTO:
This is an PLUTO
PINEAPPLE:
This is PINEAPPLE
ORANGE:
This is ORANGE
RICE:
This is RICE
```

Annotated `sed` script:

```
h;          # Copy the pattern space (the current line) into the hold space (general purpose buffer)
s/.* //;    # Remove everything up to the last space character in the pattern space
s/$/:/;     # Add colon at the end
G;          # Append the hold space (original line) with an embedded newline character
            # (implicit print)
```

Comment: With only one `s///` command, no hold copy, portable way to add a newline sed solution: `sed 'G; s/\(.*\) \(.*\)\(\n\)$/\2:\3\1 \2/' inf1`

Comment: @Isaac Your `sed` code appears to require at least one space on the line to be able to insert the colon.

Comment: If that is a problem (which the wording of the question suggests it isn't) you may use this script instead: `sed -E 'G;s/(.*)(\b[^ ]+)(\n)/\2:\3\1\2/' file`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this awk

```
awk '{$0=$NF":\n"$0}1' file
```